# Linux desktop keep randomnly freezing after recent updates

Tags: linux, chrome, freeze

I'm experiencing random desktop freezes (I have to hard shut down the system) after recent updates on my Archlinux box.
Today it happened a few minutes after startup. The only programs running were:

- Google Chrome 43.0.2357.134 (recently installed)
- Gnome shell 3.16.3
- Gnome Terminal 3.16.1
- pacman 4.2.1

My kernel version is 4.1.2-2-ARCH

The only two common things running across all freezes are kernel 4.1.2 and chrome 43.
And I started having this issues after upgrading to linux 4.1.2 and installing chrome instead of chromium. Unfortunately I did both upgrades at the same time.
Does anyone else is experiencing the same?

**EDIT:**
It seems that not even Chrome is to blame. As I had a system freeze without having run Chrome on that session. Sometimes happened with WMWare, but it also happened without having run WMWare too.
So my guess is that this is a kernel / driver issue. Today I had an update of the x86-video-intel driver... let's see if things will get better.

Comment: Use `dmesg` and look into log files under `/var/log/`

Comment: Since upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10 (with kernel 4.2), I have the same problem. However, I don't have Chrome. Also, when I boot with a previous kernel, I don't have any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mine was a kernel bug in the Bluetooth module introduced in kernel 4.1 and fixed in release 4.1.7.